# How to send SMS using modem or gateway from java Web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new in java web application and I want to send SMS from my Java web application to mobile. How can i do this using mobile/modem or any other way? any easy java API?

i really appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 1):

here is an api :

http://code.google.com/p/serial-comm/

i love this api over other is the reason that you dont have to worry about the **native libraries** and there path as this api **automatically installs** the desired native libraries to your system..

there are also other api/s like :
http://code.google.com/p/smslib/

i have recently developed an application using **serial-comm** which reads SMS from mobile/modem.

the other way around is to buy a **sms gateway service** like i use [mvaayoo](http://www.mvaayoo.com/) in that case you dont have to develop an application just use the api provided by the gateway vendor and that is just a **http link** to send SMS